# Code runs but shows no output after inputting a value

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement dp on a fibonacci sequence using vector.If i declare memo globally as an array with given size it runs fine.But while using vector it shows no output on the console.
What seems to be the problem here?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int fib(int n)
{
    vector<int>memo;
    int f;
    if(memo[n]!=0)
        return memo[n];
    if(n<=2)
        return 1;
    else
        f = fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
    memo.push_back(f);
    return f;

}

int main()
{
    int num;
    cin>>num;
    cout<<fib(num);
}
```

Comment: Seems like your fibonacci series is also wrong. 1, 1, 2, 3, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89.

Comment: Not sure why so many downvotes: not a great question by any means, but you've got a minimal complete example, a problem statement and the expected behaviour can be inferred. Welcome to Stack Overflow, this is a pretty good first question which most people don't get right!

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is your declaration of `memo`:

```
vector<int>memo;
```

It is not `static`, and thus goes out of scope every time the function exits. However, you seem to expect it to still be in scope when the function exits.

Thus, make it `static`:

```
static vector<int>memo;
```

---

Side note: I would check that `n` is less than `memo.size()` before trying to do something like `if(memo[n]!=0)`, because if `n` is greater than the size, then I believe this is undefined behavior.

Side note 2: You [shouldn't include `bits/stdC++.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: Added static and output shows garbage values.

Comment: You don't add to `memo` when `n<=21, so your vector will be shifted.

Comment: * `n<=2`. The `1` is a typo above ^

Answer (score 3):

Here's the corrected code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int fib (int n)
{
    static vector<int>memo = {1, 1}; // should be static. also init it.
    int f;
    if (n < memo.size () && memo [n] != 0) // check the size of vector before accessing
        return memo [n];
    if (n <= 2)
        return 1;
    else
        f = fib (n - 2) + fib (n - 1); // n-2 should be found and inserted before n-1
    memo.push_back (f);
    return f;

}

int main ()
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    cout << fib (num);
}
```

There were three main issues with the code.

- memo should have been declared as static. Previously with each call to fib(), it was creating a fresh 'memo' variable.
- memo[n]!=0 might cause a segfault since the vector could be small. You should check the size before referencing nth item.
- You were pushing the n'th value to (n-2)'th place. So let's first initialize the vector with {1,1}

Now the series will be generated as...
1  1  2  5  8  13  21  34  55

Comment: There were three issues with the code. Corrected the code.

Comment: There are still issues with the code. I ran this here and it does not give the correct answer.

Comment: Yes. The issue was that n-1 was getting pushed into vector before n-2. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in your code:

1. You are not allocating space on `memo` and this is why you get no output.
2. `memo` must be static so it lives over the recursion and you can get real memoization
3. You are using `memo.push_back(f);`. This defeats memoization because the indices will not correspond to what you want to find in `memo`

Fixing these issues leads to a code like this:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int fib(int n)
{
    static vector<int> memo(n + 1, 0);
    if (n > memo.capacity() - 1)  
        memo.resize(n + 1, 0);

    int f;
    if(memo[n]!=0)
        return memo[n];
    if(n<=2)
        return 1;
    else
        f = fib(n-1)+fib(n-2);
    memo[n] = f;
    return f;

}

int main()
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    cout << fib(num) << endl;
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, initialization only happens once. That means your code will work okay the first time, but what happens if a number bigger than the original `n` is passed into `fib()` a second time? That said, I like where you're going with this. You could probably do what you're trying to do better with a `std::map` instead.

Comment: Exactly `std::map` would be my way to go. I'm just trying to stick with to proposed structure. I'll think about the allocation problem.

Comment: I understand sticking to the current structure. However, you didn't address my first problem. Your code is still buggy. If something like this happens: `fib(5); fib(9);`, then a segfault will likely occur because the size initialization only happens once.

Comment: Yes, I understood in the first message. Now I fixed it. I call `resize` if needed.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. You earned an up-vote in my book.

Comment: ...and in my book as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. The reason nothing is shoring it is the program is running, but you don't know. Change to this it will show.

   `cout << "Enter a number : ";`
   `cin >> num;`
2. because you are using recursive, in the `fib()` function, you create `memo` multiple times. This will return `"program terminated with signal 11 segmentation fault"`
3. When you first call `fib()`, there's nothing in the memo, so you cannot do `memo[n]`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I changed the checking statement 
`if(memo[n]!=0)`
to this `if(!memo.empty())`.
And the rest are all the same.

Comment: You should put your comment in your original question (comments session). Not as an answer.

Comment: This won't fix the issue.

Comment: @EricChiesse I see no reason this shouldn't be an answer.

Comment: Ok, it can be. I just don't see what you wrote here as the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

This approach - recursion with memoization - is much easier with a map:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int fib(int n) {
    static map<int, int> memo;     #pairs are n, f
    int f = 0;
    if (memo.count(n) > 0)
        return memo.at(n);
    if (n <= 2 )
        return 1;
    else 
        f = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2); 
    memo.emplace(n, f);
//  cout << n << " " << f << endl;   #run this with and w/o 'static' to see effect
    return f; 
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 1, i < 12, i++)
        cout << fib(i) << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

gives:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89
```

[Edit] : Here's the vector version, it needed this loop inside however:

```
int fibVec(int n) {
    static vector<int> memo;
    int f = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < memo.size(); i++) {  //search the vector by index
        if (i == n) 
            return memo[i];
    }
    if (n <= 2 )
        return 1;
    else 
        f = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2); 
    memo.push_back(f);
    return f; 
}
```